# Post Simple Data to PHP from Xamarin Forms C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

i am trying to make a simple code for bigger project that depends on sending data to php website , but the result always empty, The Problem is both return empty result , i print the response to a label but it returns empty arrays,

### Xamarin Code is

```
private async void sendphp()
    {

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/iservices/send.php");
        var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1", "value"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param2", "value")
        };

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);
        req.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(req);

        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        lblInfo.Text = content;


    }
```

### PHP Code is :

```
<?php 
 print_r($_POST);
 print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

The Problem is both return empty result , i print the response to a label but it returns empty arrays,
i checked to server response it ok but the post is empty , why ???????
i spent 4 days trying many solution but all fails

Comment: i know $_FILES should return empty array i put it when i lost my mind, Why $_POST return empty array

Comment: finally i know the problem, i type https:// instead of http:// in my string , and it works

Comment: Now i can do it with PostAsync Aslo to send json format, just php like this

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj);

thanks [michael-sivolobov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261177/michael-sivolobov)
for [his answer in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php)

and now i can read normal KeyvaluePair using SendAsync with HttpRequest

i wil leave this to everyone whom facing the same problem , i collect answer from many places, and sorry for long text

Answer (score 0):

finally i know the problem, the question of [Tim_Kimp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066244/php-post-data-comes-up-empty-android)
inspires me to look at the .htaccess on my server, i added .htaccess in that folder and it gives me response ( 404 file not found ), hopelessly i type **https://** instead of **http://** in my string , aaaaand it works the $_POST returns a result, can't believe it, i spent 4 days in harm !
so i suggest any one have the same issue should check .httaccess or server configuration and test on local server first